# MariaDB CUstom Functions

Tags: mariadb, functions

In MySQL, I wrote functions in C++, compiled them as .so, and added them to MySQL. I am trying to find a website that shows an example for doing the same in MariaDB. I cannot find any instructions, tutorials, or examples of writing custom functions in MariaDB. Does anyone know of any or is anyone willing to write a very simple one here - like a md10 function that returns concat(md5(val),md5(val))?

Just to make it clear - I am looking to write compiled code, not define a function in SQL. It isn't just for speed. We need to clone the boxes and have all MariaDB engines fully functional.

Comment: if you are writing UDF, i think mariadb/mysql can use the same source code, at least i used some base64 libs for mysql, in mariadb without rewriting any code